# Node.js check if name matches mask

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a file mask in format like:

```
'/some/dir/*'
```

I want to match it with names:

```
'/some/dir/file1.txt'
'/some/dir/nested/file2.txt'
```

Is there a standard (common) solution in node.js to check whether name matches such mask?

I could convert mask to regExp, but I wonder if there more standard way of doing this?

Comment: I think converting it to a regex is a common way of doing this

Comment: Thought maybe some ready module for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`wildcard`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/wildcard) module can help you:

```
var wildcard = require('wildcard');
var pattern  = '/some/dir/*';
var files    = [
  '/some/dir/file1.txt',
  '/some/dir/nested/file2.txt',
  '/another/dir/file3.txt',
];

files.forEach(function(file) {
  console.log(file, 'match?', wildcard(pattern, file));
});
```